# can we validate different input fields on value change of first input fields in yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Hello Stackoverflow Family,

I have a question related to Yup, I have one select Input fields and it have 4 items on it's forth items it add two more input fields. is it possible i can apply validation on both input fields if user select the forth items from the select input fields otherwise just submit the form.

```
const YupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
workspace_name: Yup.string().trim()
    .required('Organization Name can not be Empty'),
workspace_environment: Yup.string().trim()
    .required('Workspace Environment Can not be empty'),
environment_label: Yup.string().trim()
    .required('Enviroment Label can not be Empty'),
environment_name: Yup.string().trim()
    .required('Environment Name can not be Empty')});
```

[image: This is my Select Input Fields on Click of Custom Environment it create 2 more Fields]

[image: I want it to be validate only when user select custom enviroment]

Comment: nope it is applying condition on the same fields and i couldn't find any way to validation another input fields on the basis of first input value

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would need Yup for that.
Just a simple JavaScript check for the input value and render conditionally would function.
So assuming the input select field has value of `selectedVal`, inside your component

```
let hasSelectedCustomEnv = selectedVal === 'custom_env'
...
return (
  ...
  {hasSelectedCustomEnv && <input ... />
  )
```

Comment: yeah i know it can be possible through custom javascript script but i am using yup for overall project and I don't want half of project is based on yup validation and half of the validation are custom but thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution.

```
workspace_environment: Yup.string().required("Select an Environment"),
environment_label: Yup.string().when('workspace_environment', {
    is: '1',
    then: Yup.string().required('Environment Label Required')
}),
environment_name: Yup.string().when('workspace_environment', {
    is: '1',
    then: Yup.string().required('Environment Name Required')
}),
```

that's working fine for me it's simply making environment_label and environment_name to validate only when workspace_environment has an value of "1".